# Warning on gradle after adding play-services-auth 16.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

After adding play-services-auth version 16.0.1 to implement google login on my android app I am getting a warning whereas libraries are incompatible. The warning is about mixing versions:

```
com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
```

This is the relevant part in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I am not using `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0` so I cannot understand the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using media-compat, but not directly, your dependencies use it, you can fix it by excluding:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat:26.1.0'
    }
}
```

Also, you can research all your dependencies by executing this command in terminal:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

where `app` - is your module name